# 6 points in the plane: Suppose that any triangle formed by three points will be similar to the triangle formed by the remaining three points.

Tags: geometry

There exist six points $A_1, A_2, ..., A_6$ in the plane, no three of which are collinear.

Suppose that 
any triangle formed by three points will be similar to the triangle formed by the remaining three points. If $A_1, A_2, ..., A_6$ are the vertices of a regular hexagon, we know that this property is verified.

The question is "is there any other possibility that verifies this propiety"

Thanks in advance

Comment: The property holds for any equiangular hexagon whise sides alternate between two lengths, i.e., ababab.

Comment: Yes, this hexagon verify also the property. May be we can try to determine all hexagons that verify the property?

Comment: I have an idea for a proof, but the number of cases I need to consider has tripled. By the way, where does this question come from?

Comment: @Steve B It's comes from my mind, but I don't have solution. I hope you can share your idea with me.

Comment: My first idea fell through. My current plan of attack is to prove that the two triangles in a pair of congruent triangles have the same circumcircle.